# list the data from table with grouping the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

in the sql fiddle I have listed the data that I need. I need to get the following, i need to have a last entry of all the messages with the same message_id always on the first place (just like in the emails ) and other entries with the same message_id following underneath.

It should just like in the example but obviously in 2 groups of results.

DDLs...

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
 `id` INT(5),
 `from` VARCHAR(20),
 `messages` VARCHAR(200),
 `to` VARCHAR(20),
 `message_id` INT(3)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `from`, `messages`, `to`, `message_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Andy', 'First message', 'Jack', '1'),
(2, 'Jack', 'First message reply 1', 'Andy', '1'),
(3, 'Andy', 'First message reply 2', 'Jack', '1'),
(4, 'Jack', 'First message reply 3', 'Andy', '1'),
(5, 'Andy', 'Second message', 'Jack', '2'),
(6, 'Jack', 'Second message reply 1', 'Andy', '2'),
(7, 'Jack', 'Second message reply 2', 'Andy', '2');
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f36f5/7

I think I need a sort of double sql statement where the first one takes the newest message and the second one all the other messages.

Or maybe I need the second table for such a thing.

Comment: The meaning of this is not clear: "i need to have a last entry of all the messages with the same message_id always on the first place (just like in the emails ) and other entries with the same message_id following underneath."  What is the result you are after? Can you spell it out more clearly?

Comment: What would the desired result set actually look like?

Comment: i do not know how to explain it better. I need to have for example the last entry with message_id=2 on the top and the other entries with message_id=2 listed below. i need them in 2 groups since i need with the click to show/hide the older messages. Hopefully you will understand what I mean. Just like in your email, when you receive a reply on your message, reply is shown and if you click on this reply you will get all the messages related to the last reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f36f5/15). I believe that's the result you're after. To process the results with PHP, try this:

```
/*
First we create a nested array with messages grouped by their message_id
The first few rows will be: 
$emails[1][0] = From Andy To Jack, First message
$emails[1][1] = From Jack to Andy, First message reply 1
   and so on until
$emails[2][0] = From Andy to Jack, Second message
*/

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $emails[$row['message_id']][] = $row;
}

//Uncomment this line if you want to print the structure of the array. It helps to view source on the results. 
//var_dump($emails);

//this foreach loop will run twice, providing a div for each set of messages. 
foreach ($emails as $email) {

    echo '<div class="Email_thread">';

    //this foreach loop will run for each message with a given message_id
    //swap in different HTML as needed. 
    foreach ($email as $message) {
        echo 'ID = '.$message['id'].'<br/>';
        echo 'From = '.$message['from'].'<br/>';
        echo 'To = '.$message['to'].'<br/>';    
        echo 'Message = '.$message['message'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Message_ID = '.$message['message_id'].'<br/>';        
    }

    echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: So, on the front end, will you display them one message_id at a time, or will they all appear on the same page? I.E. will you have the message_id you want, or do you just need to display ALL of the results in an organized way?

Comment: they will all appear on the same page. You can show/hide the messages with the same message_id with the click on the last entry. I want to display them one id at a time. Only the last one shown (per id) and in the background other messages with this id. I am not sure if i need 2 tables for this or only to modify my query

Comment: You can attack this several ways. When you say "2 tables" do you mean two SQL tables or two HTML tables?  Also, can you post the PHP you're using to get the records and display them? I can show you how to separate the results by message_id.

Comment: i mean 2 mysql tables, i am printing the results with the mysql_fetch_array. I am not sure how can I post a php code in this small window

Comment: Ok, there's no need for 2 mysql tables. We can handle this on the php side using arrays and loops. However, mysql_fetch_array is deprecated and has serious security issues. You should switch to mysqli functions immediately, like [mysqli_fetch_array](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and as soon as possible learn to use the new and superior [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Give me a sec and I'll edit my answer with an example of some PHP.

Comment: i need some help with the first part, what do you mean First we create a nested array with messages grouped by their message_id: The first few rows will be etc...

Comment: I got it to show me messages how we want it but now I need to hide the old messages and be able to click on the newest to show the old ones.

Comment: Hiding and showing divs is a very, very well documented process. I can give you some pointers, but first could you accept my answer?

Comment: of course, thanks a lot for your friendly help, I did not want you to show me hot to hide/show, i can do it myself only that is not exactly what i wanted. But ok I will play further, maybe i will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, your desired result should look like this:

```
"4","Jack","First message reply 3","Andy","1"
"3","Andy","First message reply 2","Jack","1"
"2","Jack","First message reply 1","Andy","1"
"1","Andy","First message","Jack","1"
"7","Jack","Second message reply 2","Andy","2"
"6","Jack","Second message reply 1","Andy","2"
"5","Andy","Second message","Jack","2"
```

To get this result in one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
ORDER BY message_id, id DESC
```

In the front end, you can loop through the rows to print/present them. Whenever a row starts with a message_id not matching with that of the previous row, you'll know that a new message starts here. So you can use that row to show the latest entry belonging to that message. The rest can be printed/presented bellow it as long as they have the same message_id. Hope it helps.